What's wrong with this YAML file for Kubernetes deployment?
I'm working with CircleCI, trying to add a component and enable release tracking.
My YAML file is as follows:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    annotations:
        circleci.com/project-id: "c145be93-a0cb-484f-acf6-c3a46c834302"
    labels:
        circleci.com/component-name: com.chronotext
        circleci.com/version: 1.0.0
    name: com.chronotext
    namespace: default
spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                circleci.com/component-name: com.chronotext
                circleci.com/version: 1.0.0

When I do a kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml, I get the following error:
* spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string(nil), MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: empty selector is invalid for deployment
* spec.template.spec.containers: Required value

The documentation in CircleCi is very cryptic to me:
A component in CircleCI is a collection of code and configuration deployed and released as a single unit. In Kubernetes terms, this would be a Deployment or Rollout object along with the related objects such as Pods, ReplicaSets, etc. that share a common circleci.com/component-name label..
Example: Labels and annotation added to a Kubernetes Deployment manifest
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    annotations:
        circleci.com/project-id: {{ your-project-ID }}
    labels:
        circleci.com/component-name: example-deployment
        circleci.com/version: 1.0.0
    name: example-deployment
    namespace: default
spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
          ...
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                ...
                circleci.com/component-name: example-deployment
                circleci.com/version: 1.0.0


Where did you learn to write that format? It is far from a Kubernetes Deployment yaml manifest. Also the error is appropriate, your matchLabels are emtpy.

I just added at the end of my post the "template" Kubernetes deployment manifest provided at CircleCI

The matchLabels and labels attributes should not be empty.
They should be based on the information provided in the metadata section.
Based on the yaml you have provided it should be the following:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    circleci.com/project-id: "c145be93-a0cb-484f-acf6-c3a46c834302"
  labels:
    circleci.com/component-name: com.chronotext
    circleci.com/version: 1.0.0
  name: com.chronotext
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: com.chronotext
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: com.chronotext
        circleci.com/component-name: com.chronotext
        circleci.com/version: 1.0.0

You can find an example here: CircleCi - Configure your Kubernetes components - Example Deployment
Presuming, by the question you were intentionally only showing part of the yaml due to the exceptions thrown.
If not, the yaml is incomplete, specifically it is missing the spec and containers sections within the Pod template. This is crucial because Kubernetes needs to know which containers to run and how to run them.
Refer to the link above

Thanks @djmonki but I gave up the idea of working with CircleCI. Their documentation is far too cryptic for me
